# NSIS Embed Uninstaller readRegStr Filepath

Tags: nsis, filepath, uninstallation

I have an uninstaller created with HM NIS Edit. And as of now it is executing the uninstaller from a static path. But I want to make it dynamic. It has to read the reg and then uses that path as a prefix for to find the uninstaller.

```
readRegStr $0 HKLM "SOFTWARE\Data Access Worldwide\Visual DataFlex\17.0\Defaults" VDFRootDir
```

I hope I made myself clear.

Comment: The path of the uninstall .exe cannot really be dynamic since it is usually registered so the control panel can find it. Do you mean the path where the uninstaller is supposed to remove files from?

Comment: It only needs to read the registry to find out where VDF is installed so I can use that as a prefix for the uninstaller for example.
It reads that the path where VDF is installed is: C:\Appl\Visual DataFlex 17.0\

So the uninstaller will be in: C:\Appl\Visual DataFlex 17.0\Uninstall Visual DataFlex 17.0.22.0\UNWISE.EXE

I hope I made myself clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can join strings with StrCpy:

```
ReadRegStr $0 HKLM "SOFTWARE\Data Access Worldwide\Visual DataFlex\17.0\Defaults" VDFRootDir
StrCpy $0 "$0\Uninstall Visual DataFlex 17.0.22.0\UNWISE.EXE"
ExecWait '"$0"'
```

You don't even need StrCpy if you only use the string once:

```
ReadRegStr $0 HKLM "SOFTWARE\Data Access Worldwide\Visual DataFlex\17.0\Defaults" VDFRootDir
ExecWait '"$0\Uninstall Visual DataFlex 17.0.22.0\UNWISE.EXE"'
```

Comment: Lol I literally went from 20 lines of code to 5.
Thanks Anders!